# count query in mysql is not giving result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask a query in mysql, I have a table that look like this:

**Table XYZ**

```
sender                      reciever

  1                            2
  1                            3
  2                            2
  4                            1
  5                            0
  7                            5
  8                            5
```

the requirement is:

find those entries in reciever whose frequency in reciever is greater than frequency in senders column.

That means the output should be

```
reciever

2
3
0
5
```

I have tried it like:

```
SELECT reciever 
FROM XYZ
WHERE count(reciever)>count(sender)
```

Comment: how you calculate count?

Comment: Atleast you should give the reason in comments before voting down

Comment: Remove count and check the sql. Count is used to find no' of records. Not the column value

Comment: I have to find those values in reciever whose frequency in reciever is greater than frequency in sender column. Hope u got that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*find the numbers having count in reciver > count in sender*. So count each number repetitions in `reciver` and in `sender` and then compare counts. I use `LEFT JOIN` as there can by numbers in `reciever`, which isn't in `sender`:

```
SELECT r.reciever
FROM (
  SELECT reciever, COUNT(*) cnt
   FROM XYZ
   GROUP BY reciever
) r
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT sender, COUNT(*) cnt
   FROM XYZ
   GROUP BY sender
) s ON s.sender = r.reciever AND s.cnt < r.cnt
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT reciever 
  FROM XYZ
 WHERE reciever > sender
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to simply compare the frequencies. To do that, you can count the frequencies for the two columns in two separate subqueries, then join them for the comparison. The LEFT JOIN is to not eliminate hits that don't exist in `SENDER`;

```
SELECT a.reciever
FROM (SELECT reciever, COUNT(*) c FROM mytable GROUP BY reciever) a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sender, COUNT(*) c2  FROM mytable GROUP BY sender) b
  ON a.reciever = b.sender AND c<=c2
WHERE sender IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfa360/1).